# Symfony 2 - No route found for "GET /"

Tags: symfony, get

I followed instructions from here: http://www.kevwebdev.com/blog/setting-up-a-symfony2-project-in-phpstorm.html on how to install symfony2 with phpstorm.

I did everything but after I run my untouched symfony2 framework I'm getting this error: No route found for "GET /"

Please see this image for full preview: http://s28.postimg.org/jl4curnvx/Untitled.jpg

Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, please check routing.yml or otherwise put your app/config/routing.yml and ACME/../routing.yml here.

Comment: I'm begginer, sorry. My routing is empty. What should I put inside my routing?

Comment: what happens if you access /app_dev.php/  ? if that works youre missing a rewrite rule

Comment: No route found for "GET /app.dev.php"

Comment: Do you use annotations or routing.yml file ?

Answer (score 0):

***Add below code in  symfony_root/app/config/routing.yml***

if AppBundle DefaultController indexAction exist then it work, other follow you ***Bundle*** structure !

```
_welcome:
pattern:  /
defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Default:index }
requirements: { _method:  GET }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can check current routing settings with:

```
./app/console router:debug
```

or

`./bin/console router:debug`

for Symfony3 structure